# jQuery toggle() with dblclick() changing display to none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have created a div that when I double click it, it will expand the entire contents of the div to full screen. I now want to be able to toggle this when double clicking so it goes back to original size.

The code was working to increase the div size, but once adding the toggle() function, it now changes the display to none when I double click the first time. I assume I am just using toggle incorrectly, but am unable to figure out how to make this work.

#### HTML

```
<div class="popout-box">
  <button id="btnShow">Wallboard</button>
    <div class='menu' style='display: none'>
    <div id="framewrap">
    <button id="btnHide">Close</button><br/>
      <iframe id="frame" src="https://url.com">
      </iframe>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### jQUery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#framewrap").dblclick(function(){
        $("#framewrap").toggle().css({"width":"100%","height":"100%","position":"fixed","left":"0px","right":"0px","top":"5px","bottom":"0px"});
        });
    });
```

#### CSS

```
#framewrap {
    background-color:#1886c5;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #333;
}
#frame {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#1886c5;
}
.popout-box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.menu {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: try to not use the function `.dblclick(function(){})` as it is more normal to say: `.on("dblclick", function(){})`

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Read what toggle does.

Comment: toggle doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I would suggest assigning those css rules to a class in your stylesheet and then using toggleClass instead of toggle and css

Comment: Any advice? I just want to be able to doubleclick it again and have the css go back to what it was before.

Comment: [jQuery.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) might be what you are looking for (with all the css in a class).

Comment: @Fallenreaper, what's more "normal" about it? how is it better?

Comment: "if you can't explain it simply you don't understand it well enough" - someone famous said that.. idr who. einstein maybe, but anyway, after reading your link i still see no advantage. especially not in this situation. this is NOT a dynamically created element, and for the record, `.off()` works just fine whether you use `on` or an alias of it.. http://jsfiddle.net/m3r55mcn/ so anyway, if you could explain simply in a comment why the aliases are not ok to use, i would appreciate that. @NeilS

Comment: @NeilS, you got a unique attitude.

Comment: @Aldentec I haven't seen your fiddle. Are there _any_ differences in your fiddle and your site?

Comment: Hey Neil, the fiddle works perfectly fine. There are some differences such as I have some other jQuery running on my site. However, I did remove all other scripts and it still won't work.

Comment: @Aldentec can you make the Fiddle exactly like your site? If it works in a fiddle, but not on your site, I would think that it's something on your site that is causing a conflict. Did you check your console for any errors? Unless you can show us all how it's not working on your site, I'm not sure we're going to be able to help much.

Comment: Understood. I checked console, no errors. I also pasted all the code into the fiddle and it works! Yet still, not working on my site. Still troubleshooting. Here is the fiddle, although not sure it will help you any.

https://jsfiddle.net/avdg03c3/

Comment: @NeilS, I think you can't admit you're wrong that's all. If you want to explain what it's better go ahead, if you just want to keep linking to blogs\answers you didn't understand, please don't ping me.

Comment: @Aldentec well, there are a few problems with your code, I'm not sure if they are causing problems on your site, but you have 3 separate DOM ready function blocks, and your mouse event handlers are declared outside them. Also, I think you might have conflicts with your event handlers, since both the mouse up and mouse down events will be triggered during a double-click. You also have an extra closing div tag that's not necessary. Not sure if any of this helps, but good luck

Comment: @Aldentec - You're allowed to have as many `ready()` calls as your little heart desires, the rest of those were really good points though.. I'd like to add a few. 1) You do not need body tags in a jsFiddle, the body already exists, so that might cause a problem if you ever tried to reference the body in a fiddle. 2) The fiddle you provided using `toggleClass()` works fine, but if you expect to see a difference, you had better declair the class you're toggling :P https://jsfiddle.net/avdg03c3/4/ not a dramatic change, you'll need to correct the CSS, I'm lazy.

Comment: i agree niel, but that's not relevant. he's not asking how he can optimize his site, he's asking how to fix a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#framewrap").dblclick(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('newClass');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.newClass
{
     width:100%,
     height:100%,
     ...
     ...
 }
```

Comment: This isn't working. Could it be because I am also using jQuery UI? That seems to be assigning classes based on resizeable and draggable. Would that interrupt the toggleClass()?

Comment: jquery ui IS jquery, they're built to work together, so no, jqui is not interfering.

Comment: @Aldentec, create a demo on jsfiddle.net please

Comment: @Adelphia, not quite true, if you add jQuery UI, things change, though they indeed implemented to work together.

Comment: Working on a jsfiddle. for some reason having issues >.<

Comment: Selected as correct answer as it is a solution to this problem. However, I have some sort of other thing conflicting with this, as this works in jsfiddle, but not for my site.

Comment: Just curious, any thoughts on what might prevent this from working?The code I posted originally will work to expand the div when I take the toggle piece out, so I don't think it's a jQuery conflict. Seems like adding toggleClass() is what made it not work. 

Like I said, works great in jsfiddle. I am using the same version of jQuery as the fiddle.

Comment: @Aldentec, no idea, try removing stuff from your page until it works on your page too. Without seeing the code I'm afraid that's all I can say.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#framewrap").on('dblclick', function() {
        $("#framewrap").toggleClass('fixed');
    });
});
```

CSS

```
.fixed { 
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:5px;
    bottom:0
}
```